# No permission for custom backend role in Opensearch dashboard (kibana)

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, opensearch, opensearch-dashboards, opensearch-security-plugin

I have opensearch running and keycloak as oidc provider and I get this 403 error after login to opensearch:

```
{"statusCode":403,"error":"Forbidden","message":"no permissions for [indices:data/read/search] and User [name=demo.demo, backend_roles=[kibana_second], requestedTenant=null]: security_exception"}
```

As default we have "*kibana_user*" role which has "*kibanauser*" as backend role. If my oidc user "*demo.demo*" has "*kibanauser*" role attached to it, everything works fine and this user has permission to see dashboards, discover and index patterns.

```
User [name=demo.demo, backend_roles=[kibanauser]..]
```

But this role is dangerous to assign to every user because the user can delete an index pattern or change the global setting. I want to have the a role only to view dashboard and discover. At the first step, also i duplicated "*kibana_user*" role with the new name "*kibana_user_copy*" and mapped it to the new backend role created by me "*kibana_second*". The backend role was also attached it to my user in oidc provider. Means:

```
User [name=demo.demo, backend_roles=[kibana_second]..]
```

So far good, now as you see the error, my "*demo.demo*" user has new backend role and it has all permissions that "*kibana_user*" would have. (because "*kibana_user_copy*" is a duplicate of "*kibana_user*". What I'm wondering, all permissions are the same, only backend role is not predefined "*kibanauser*". But It doesn't work and I see only blank pages for dashboard and discover (403).

Has anyone an idea, what is missing here?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Issue was solved by adding tenancy to this duplicated role